# Cloud-Init boot takes One Hour+ to start

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

[image]

Hello Everyone,

I am looking to understand what process is running that halting the boot up of our ubuntu VM's that was originally configured with cloud-init. The after the entries paint in the picture the system hangs for a significant time (1 hours+) before advancing to boot.

Ubuntu version 18.04
Azure VM

Due to the apps that we are running and its conflicts. We are interested in removing Cloud-Init altogether but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Thanks,

Comment: `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemctl --failed` can help you narrow down which services are failing, blocking boot, or taking too long.

Comment: cloud-init expects the VM to be running on a host or hosting service providing an amazon ec2-compatible metadata service on 169.254.169.254 (e.g. AWS itself, openstack, or something like my [fakecloud](https://github.com/craig-sanders/fakecloud) server).  It tries to query the metadata service to get config details like hostname, ip address, ssh keys, etc.  If the metadata service isn't running or not available for some other reason, that can cause long boot delays.  If you don't have such a service, then you probably should uninstall cloud-init and rely on static or dhcp config.